# How to pass event in onClick in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to to call "preventDefault" in some manner on a custom component without success.  Here are my attempts.  The first attempt with "e" passes the element reference and not the actual event.  The second method passes the event, but the prevent default method does not prevent anything.  What is the best way to do this?

```
<MyComponent header= {
    <div onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); myFunction.bind(this, event) }}>
       Header
    </div> 
} />

function myFunction(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing jsx through props?

Comment: If you end doing something like this, keep looking, because there should be a better way

Comment: @notgiorgi - I am already using "Children" for another jsx property, so I did not have any other place left to pass the header jsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
<MyComponent header={<div onClick={myFunction}>Header</div>} />

function myFunction(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Or, if you need to use `this` in the click handler:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  myFunction = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ clicked: true });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <MyComponent header={<div onClick={this.myFunction}>Header</div>} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The fat arrow (`=>`) does this for you. But if you can't use ES6 features yet, you'd have to bind it explicitly...

Comment: @tobiasandersen - When I do it this way, a reference to the element gets passed to "myFunction", not the actual event.  Is that because my function  is outside the class?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Are you doing it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ybv6mtg0/?

Comment: @tobiasandersen - Kind of, except I am using typescript instead of javascript.